# should my data for a linear regression have a roughly equal number of X values for each different Y value?

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression

I'm trying to set up my data for a linear regression, and I want to make sure my results will be meaningful in the end.

I work for a small insurance company, and I'm trying to do a linear regression analysis on the **effect of rainfall amounts on number of auto claims** (a "claim" is an insurance term for an accident).  Lets say I'm focusing specifically on **Houston, Texas.**

Imagine that the **x axis is rainfall**, lets say the buckets will be 0cm, 1-5cm, 6-10cm, 11-15cm and so on.
The **y axis ** will be number of claims.  100,125, 140, 150 etc.

I have easy access to this information from my company's database, but **my question is...**
**Do I need to have a roughly equal number of X values for each Y "bucket"**

You can imagine that it would be very very easy to find days with 0 rain fall.  So this bucket could potentially have much much more observations than others.  To put it another way, days with >30cm are gonna be rare, so I may not have very many observations for that rainfall amount.

Should I try to get a roughly equal number of observations for each Y value, or should I just get as much as possible?  Thank you for the help!

I'll be working in python, but this is obviously more of a theory question.

Comment: Not,not at all.

Also, initially a simple linear regression without bucketing X values can be run to see where the model is heading.

Comment: @Prachi, could you expand on this?  Are you saying it's okay to have large differences in the number of measurements for each value of the X variable?

Comment: The way you are trying to approach the problem statement is through convert continuous X column values into categorical.
Here are few links that might help you - https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/mks/statmistakes/dividingcontinuousintocategories.html

https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/continuous-and-categorical-variables-the-trouble-with-median-splits/#:~:text=A%20Median%20Split%20is%20one,it%20is%20labeled%20%E2%80%9CHigh.%E2%80%9D

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a good ML model, the chosen sample to train the model should be a near representation of the population. Else the model would be biased. It would provide accurate prediction of the class for which there is sufficient instance in the training set but not for those categories where the number of sample is very limited. I assume that you would be splitting the data into training and test set.

I would recommend to use the Stratified sampling instead of Randomized sampling. The below library would be helpful. Prior to using make sure to check the different bins of rainfall.

```
from sklearn.model_selection StratifiedShuffleSplit

split = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index in split.split(df, df[<<column name>>]):
    strat_train_set = df.loc[train_index]
    strat_test_set = df.loc[test_index]
```

Comment: hmm to be honest, I'm just learning some Stats stuff, so I was going to just stick with the linear regression.  Can you clarify what you mean when you say that the data should be a near representation of the population?  In Houston TX, there are going to be ALOT more days when there is 0cm rainfall, then when there is > 0cm rainfall.  So is it okay to have ALOT more measurements for where X (rain fall amount) = 0 ?

Comment: @aaronrums, the model would be more suitable and reliable to predict for cases when the X's = 0 but not so much for the days for X's > 0 . The prime reason being that the dataset is not balanced but is heavily skewed to the fact where X's=0.  The label you want to predict is Claim is High Medium or Low (as I understand). This would become a classification regression problem. If you train the model using randomized split and evaluate on the test set, you might get a high accuracy score. But accuracy score is sensitive to bias in the dataset.

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28227/why-will-the-accuracy-of-a-highly-unbalanced-dataset-reduce-after-oversampling